# Use infinite row argument in ISDTATE function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using the sumifs formula to check for two conditions.

```
=sumifs('Invoices Sent'!K:K,'Invoices Sent'!B:B,"<"&B17, 'Invoices Sent'!O:O,">="&B18)
```

I want to add the third condition that the value in cell in column 0 is a date. How do I format this condition for the sumifs function? I think ISDATE can only take a cell.

```
=sumifs('Invoices Sent'!K:K,'Invoices Sent'!B:B,"<"&B17, 'Invoices Sent'!O:O,">="&B18, 'Invoices Sent'!O:O,ISDATE())
```

I need to use infinite rows as I don't want to keep changing the formula each time I add a row. By infinite rows I mean, a start and end row index is not specified.

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Add this as the third condition within your `sumif()`; also assuming your `Column O` has valid date-format*

```js
index(isdate_strict('Invoices Sent'!O:O)), true
```

Comment: Thanks @rockinfreakshow.  Very much appreciated. That solved the problem for me. However I have a follow up question. If I want the sum logic to be as follows:
Sum if Condition 1 and (Condition 2 or Condition 3)
condition 1 : Cell has date less than B17
condition 2: Cell has date greater than B18
condition 3: Cell has no date

Comment: Share a test sheet showcasing your scenario (input + expected outcome manually entered) and I can check it out.

Comment: thanks @rockingfreakshow The sheet that I have is quite sensitive, and I can't share it directly, and I am likely to get to trouble if I do share it directly. I will try and make a mock up, but that isn't a quick exercise for me. Nevertheless I will do this and create a new question and will ping you when I do it. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUM along with FILTER. IFNA is for the case there's no row that meets all the conditions:

```
=SUM(IFNA(FILTER('Invoices Sent'!K:K,'Invoices Sent'!B:B<B17,'Invoices Sent'!O:O>=B18,ISDATE('Invoices Sent'!O:O))))
```

Comment: Thanks @Martin . I tried this and it didn't work for me. I double checked the cell being checked was in the correct date format by seeing how it affected the result of the formula I posted about above.

Comment: You should share some sample data, and a spreadsheet were we could test what's happening